# Animating list items one after one using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this list items :

```
    <ul id="right-menu">
        <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

with these styles:

```
#right-menu {
z-index: 0;
position: relative;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 0;
float: right;
width: 185px;
}
#right-menu li {
width: 200px;
height: 54px;
background-image: url(../menu-fullbg.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
color: #fff;
right: -200px;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
padding: 5px;
}
```

and this JQuery code:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(0)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 500);
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(1)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 1000);
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(2)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 1300);
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(3)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 1600);
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(4)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 2000);
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(5)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 2500);
});
```

and I want to animate them when the page loads one after one but with this code the last li item doesn't show up, and when I replace the last line of code with this:

```
$("#right-menu li:last-child").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 2500);
```

the li item before that disappears!!!
what's the problem here?? I don't get it. what's the proper and efficient way to do this??
please help...

Comment: instead of too many `animate()` statements use this http://jsfiddle.net/LS8MG/

Answer (score 1):

`nth-child` is 1-based like the CSS selector of the same name: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
 $(window).load(function() {
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(1)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 500);
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(2)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 1000);
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(3)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 1300);
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(4)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 1600);
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(5)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 2000);
      $("#right-menu li:nth-child(6)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 2500);
});
```

*Bit of a shame they introduced this inconsistency, just to avoid clashing with the CSS selector.*

Other selectors like `:eq()` are  0-based e.g.:

```
$("#right-menu li:eq(0)").animate({ right: "-100px" }, 500);
```

You can reduce the code with an `each` loop, calculating the duration based on the sequential index (which in this case is 0-based):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/LS8MG/1/

```
$("#right-menu li").each(function(index){
    $(this).animate({ right: "-100px" }, index * 500 + 500);
});
```

Update:

You should use the shortcut version of document ready instead of `window.load()`:

```
$(function() {
     // your code here
});
```

If you need to avoid $ naming clashes, this rather cool variation:

```
jQuery(function($) {
     // your code using a local $
});
```

`$(function(){ your code here });` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){ your code here });`

Comment: jQuery's `eq()` selector is 0 based btw.

Comment: @Scimonster: I never said it wasn't :) The whole thing needed a loop anyway, so using *any* child selector was pointless.

Comment: No, but i was just mentioning, since you didn't say anything about using it.

Comment: @Scimonster: Not really any value here, as the code would be just as bad using `:eq()` or `.eq()` 6 times :) I *will* mention it though. *All a waste of time as the SO is ignoring this answer* :(